# Guava EventBus dispatching

Tags: java, guava

I'm using Guava's EventBus to kick off some processing and report results.  Here's a very simple compilable example:

```
import com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus;
import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;

public class Test {

    public static class InitiateProcessing { }
    public static class ProcessingStarted { }
    public static class ProcessingResults { }
    public static class ProcessingFinished { }

    public static EventBus bus = new EventBus();

    @Subscribe
    public void receiveStartRequest(InitiateProcessing evt) {
        System.out.println("Got processing request - starting processing");
        bus.post(new ProcessingStarted());

        System.out.println("Generating results");
        bus.post(new ProcessingResults());
        System.out.println("Generating more results");
        bus.post(new ProcessingResults());

        bus.post(new ProcessingFinished());
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void processingStarted(ProcessingStarted evt) {
        System.out.println("Processing has started");
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void resultsReceived(ProcessingResults evt) {
        System.out.println("got results");
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void processingComplete(ProcessingFinished evt) {
        System.out.println("Processing has completed");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        bus.register(t);
        bus.post(new InitiateProcessing());
    }
}
```

I use these events as a way for other software components to react in preparation for this processing.  For example, they may have to save their current state before processing and restore it after.

I would expect the output of this program to be:

```
Got processing request - starting processing
Processing has started
Generating results
got results
Generating more results
got results
Processing has completed
```

Instead, the actual output is:

```
Got processing request - starting processing
Generating results
Generating more results
Processing has started
got results
got results
Processing has completed
```

The event that is supposed to indicate that processing has started actually happens after the actual processing ("generating results").

After looking at the source code, I understand why it's behaving this way.  Here's the relevant [source code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v18.0/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.java) for the `EventBus`.

```
  /**
   * Drain the queue of events to be dispatched. As the queue is being drained,
   * new events may be posted to the end of the queue.
   */
  void dispatchQueuedEvents() {
    // don't dispatch if we're already dispatching, that would allow reentrancy
    // and out-of-order events. Instead, leave the events to be dispatched
    // after the in-progress dispatch is complete.
    if (isDispatching.get()) {
        return;
    }
    // dispatch event (omitted)
```

What's happening is since I'm already dispatching the top level `InitiateProcessing` event, the rest of the events just get pushed to the end of the queue.  I would like this to behave  similar to .NET events, where invoking the event doesn't return until all handlers have completed.

I don't quite understand the reason for this implementation.  Sure, the events are guaranteed to be in order, but the order of the surrounding code gets completely distorted.

Is there any way to get the bus to behave as described and produce the desired output?  I did read in the Javadocs that

> The EventBus guarantees that it will not call a subscriber method from
>   multiple threads simultaneously, unless the method explicitly allows
>   it by bearing the @AllowConcurrentEvents annotation.

But I don't think this applies here - I'm seeing this issue in a single threaded application.

**Edit**

The cause of the issue here is that I'm `post`ing from within a subscriber.  Since the event bus is not reentrant, these "sub-posts" get queued up and are handled after the first handler completes.  I can comment out the `if (isDispatching.get()) { return; }` section in the `EventBus` source and everything behaves as I would expect - so the real question is what potential problems have I introduced by doing so?  It seems the designers made a conscientious decision to not allow reentrancy.

Comment: looks like the event bus runs in it's own thread. That means usually, that the actions are performed asynchronously and (as soon it's a bus) guaranteed to be delivered according to its' order, and it has nothing to do with the main thread

Comment: @injecteer It does not run it's own thread.  They do have an `AsyncEventBus` that allows you to specify an `Executor` - but I'm not using that.  This is all single threaded.

Comment: you might be right. Although I think, they DO run in a new thread :) Can you please test it by adding `System.out.println( "curr thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() )` to each of your processing `@Subscribe`-d methods?

Comment: Why do you .post() from _within_ a subscriber to begin with? Something is fishy here

Comment: That's exactly why I'm seeing this problem. Is that not a valid use case?   Conceptually, events can trigger other events - we've been operating under the assumption that this was okay.

Comment: Admittedly it feels a little weird that the exact synchronicity of event posting depends on whether or not the method posting the events was called in the handling of another event or not, but as I said in my answer, code that's posting events should not be concerned with when or how they're handled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`EventBus` generally operates on the principle that the code posting an event to the bus shouldn't care about what the subscribers do with the events or when, other than that the order the events were posted in is respected (in the case of a synchronous event bus anyway).

If you want specific methods to be called at specific times in the course of your method and you want to be sure those methods complete before your method continues (as you seem to in your example), why not call those methods directly? When you use an event bus, you're explicitly separating your code from what exactly happens in response to a given event. This is desirable in many cases and is the main reason `EventBus` exists, but it doesn't seem to be quite what you want here.

Comment: "Separating my code from what exactly happens in response to a given event" *is* what I want.  I want the event to say "get ready for something to happen" - I don't care how or what subscribers have to do to get ready.  They might not have to do anything.  I just want to be confident that after posting the event, the subscribers are ready so I can proceed with some action.  The event bus seems perfect for this case because I can easily add and remove components that might handle the event differently.  The code posting the event doesn't care.

Comment: What I am taking out of the answers so far is that this behavior is by design and the event bus as is will not support my use case.  I ended up modifying the bus to allow reentrancy which better suits my use case.

Answer (score 7):

I try to summarize Guava's EventBus event delivery behaviour:

If an event *E1* is posted at moment *t1*, all subscribers are notified. 
If one of the subscribers posts an event itself in it's *@Subscribe*-method (a tiny moment later), the "new" event *E2* is enqueued and delivered **afterwards**. Afterwards means here: after all *@Subscribe*-methods for *E1* from *t1* did return.

Compare this kind of "cascaded" event posting to breadth first tree traversal.

It seems to be the explicit choosen design of EventBus.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is 4 years old, but I just ran into the same problem today. There is a simple (and counter-intuitive) change to get the behavior you want. Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/53136251/1296767, you can use an AsyncEventBus with a DirectExecutor:

```
public static EventBus bus = new AsyncEventBus(MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService());
```

Running your test code with the above change, the results are exactly what you want:

```
Got processing request - starting processing
Processing has started
Generating results
got results
Generating more results
got results
Processing has completed
```

Answer (score 2):

While posting to the EventBus does not return until all "subscribers" have been signaled .. those subscribers might NOT have begun execution. That means that when the first bus.post returns, you continue the next post without any intervening subscriber having begun to process.

> public void post(Object event) Posts an event to all registered
>   subscribers. This method will return successfully after the event has
>   been posted to all subscribers, and regardless of any exceptions
>   thrown by subscribers. If no subscribers have been subscribed for
>   event's class, and event is not already a DeadEvent, it will be
>   wrapped in a DeadEvent and reposted.
>
> Parameters: event - event to post.

Comment: This isn't quite right - in this case the when the first post returns all of the events have been handled.  Either way - this doesn't answer my question about whether I can get the bus to behave as expected.