# Guava EventBus delaying handler execution of nested events

Tags: java, guava, event-bus

My issue is pretty identical to [Guava EventBus dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947936/guava-eventbus-dispatching), but while the underlying issue is similar, my attempted fix has left me in the dark.

I have 2 events that are fired back to back. The 2nd event is dependant on the final state of the first event after all handlers are done with it. It should only fire if the 1st event wasn't cancelled. The catch is that both of these events are fired from within another event's handler.

So while I don't care who listens to the 1st nested event, I do care what they have to say about it. Am I already leaving the problemspace that events and Guava's EventBus aim to solve?

Considering:

```
public void parentEventHandler(ParentEvent parentEvent) {
    Object nestedEvent = createNestedEvent();
    eventBus.post(nestedEvent);

    if(nestedEvent.isCancelled()) {
        return;
    }

    Object anotherNestedEvent = createOtherNestedEvent();
    eventBus.post(anotherNestedEvent);
}
```

What I expected:

```
1. parentEvent is posted
2. parentEventHandler is called
3. nestedEvent is posted
4. handlers of nestedEvent are called
5. finished handling nestedEvent
6. if statement checks for cancel state of nestedEvent
7.     anotherNestedEvent is posted if nestedEvent not cancelled
8.     handlers of anotherNestedEvent are called
9.     finished handling anotherNestedEvent
10 finished handling parentEvent
```

What is happening:

```
1. parentEvent is posted
2. parentEventHandler is called
3. nestedEvent is posted
4. if statement checks for cancel state of nestedEvent (defaults to false)
5.     anotherNestedEvent is posted
6. finished handing parentEvent
7. handlers of nestedEvent are called
8. nestedEvent is cancelled (too late now)
9. finished handling nestedEvent
10 handlers of anotherNestedEvent are called
11 finished handling anotherNestedEvent
```

At point 8. regardless of whether the handler cancels the event the second event has already been queued since the cancel check defaults to false. Guava's EventBus insists on finishing its current handler run before starting the next event's, which I'm sure has its uses, but its not what I'm looking for.

**Attempted hack:**

I noticed that Guava has an implementation for an ImmediateDispatcher (https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/Dispatcher.java#L179) available that publishes events as they come in contrary to the behaviour of saving events until the current one has been handled by all subscribers of the default PerThreadQueuedDispatcher (https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/Dispatcher.java#L73).

However, these other dispatchers are package private and there's no public API on the EventBus to change the dispatcher to use. Forking Guava and changing the default dispatcher at https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.java#L122 and L136 to `Dispatcher.immediate()`, re-installing Guava locally under another version number, and fat jarring that custom build into my project the observed behaviour of events in the application hasn't changed at all. And now I'm completely lost.

Is there a way to achieve strict LIFO event dispatching with Guava's EventBus or is there a different paradigm I should be looking at rather than events that would make more sense when events can be cancelled and frequently end up nested in other event handlers? I don't care how many and which subscribers listen to the events, but I do want to know what they have to say about the event (i.e. whether they decided if it should be cancelled or not). The application is entirely single threaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the "regular" `EventBus`, you can get this to work by creating a secondary event.

Add an interface `InternalEventCallback` and a class `InternalEventCallbackHandler`:

```
interface InternalEventCallback {
    void run();
}

class InternalEventCallbackHandler {

    @Subscribe
    public void internalEventHandler(InternalEventCallback r){
        r.run();
    }
}
```

Where you are creating your `EventBus`, register the `InternalEventCallbackHandler`:

```
eventBus.register(new InternalEventCallbackHandler());
```

Then in your `parentEventHandler` do:

```
@Subscribe
public void parentEventHandler(ParentEvent parentEvent) {
    NestedEvent nestedEvent = createNestedEvent();
    eventBus.post(nestedEvent);
    eventBus.post(new InternalEventCallback() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(nestedEvent.isCancelled()) {
                return;
            }

            Object anotherNestedEvent = createOtherNestedEvent();
            eventBus.post(anotherNestedEvent);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

If you use the `AsyncEventBus` together with the "direct executor", you can get the same behaviour as in the example above, but without `InternalEventCallback` and `InternalEventCallbackHandler`

```
EventBus eventBus = new AsyncEventBus(MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService());
```

Comment: Interesting! While this will solve my issue at the moment, it does kind of start to smell. Is this approach a well accepted solution to working with nested events or should I still be looking at rethinking the use of Guava's EventBus in this particular usecase?

Comment: I agree about the "smell". I don't know if this solution is "well accepted", since most users don't have the same requirement as you. I have updated my answer with an alternate solution.

Comment: The edit does indeed do what I need. The fact that that worked got me to think hard about why my synchronous hack didn't work though. Turns out my custom Guava build was being overwritten by an already bundled older version of Guava from the host application (ofcourse it did). Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my custom Guava build was being overwritten by an already bundled older version of Guava from the host application (ofcourse it did). I ended up applying the hack through code (probably not very resilient to version changes):

```
public GuavaEventService() {
    this.bus = new EventBus();
    try {
        Field dispatcherField = EventBus.class.getDeclaredField("dispatcher");
        dispatcherField.setAccessible(true);
        Class<?> dispatcherClass = dispatcherField.get(this.bus).getClass().getSuperclass();
        Method immediateDispatcher = dispatcherClass.getDeclaredMethod("immediate");
        immediateDispatcher.setAccessible(true);
        dispatcherField.set(this.bus, immediateDispatcher.invoke(null));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to initialize event service dispatcher: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

However, eiden suggested a much cleaner Async event bus alternative in the edit of his answer:
`EventBus eventBus = new AsyncEventBus(MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService());`

Comment: `MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService()` runs on the calling thread. So it never creates new threads.